# pygame bitmask collision won't work

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, collision

Though it the collision is detected when I use `pygame.sprite.collide_rect` or `pygame.sprite.collide_circle`, when I try to assign a bitmask to a sprite, and run it as so, the collision is not detected. (The `wall.collision_action()` makes the first circle move at the same speed and direction of the other circle) Though this is not a concern now,
as I am using images of circles which makes the pygame.sprite.collide_circle work fine, in the future when I am using more detailed and non-circular sprites it will be.

code:

```
import pygame, sys, math
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

class ball_class(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, surface):
        self.surface = surface
        self.x = 250
        self.y = 250
        self.vy = 0
        self.vx = 0
        self.sprite = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
        self.sprite.image = pygame.image.load("ball.png").convert()
        self.sprite.rect = self.sprite.image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))
        self.sprite.rect.topleft = [int(self.x), int(self.y)]
        self.sprite.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.sprite.image)

    def event(self, event):
        if event.key == K_UP:
            self.vy = -1
            self.vx = 0
        elif event.key == K_DOWN:
            self.vy = 1
            self.vx = 0
        elif event.key == K_LEFT:
            self.vx = -1
            self.vy = 0
        elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
            self.vx = 1
            self.vy = 0

    def move(self):
        self.y += self.vy
        self.x += self.vx
        self.sprite.rect.topleft = [int(self.x), int(self.y)]
        self.sprite.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.sprite.image)

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.sprite.image, self.sprite.rect)

    def position(self):
        return self.sprite.rect()

class wall_class(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, surface):
        self.surface = surface
        self.x = 250
        self.y = 100
        self.vy = 0
        self.sprite = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
        self.sprite.image = pygame.image.load("ball.png").convert()
        self.sprite.rect = self.sprite.image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))
        self.sprite.rect.topleft = [int(self.x), int(self.y)]
        self.sprite.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.sprite.image)

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.sprite.image, self.sprite.rect)

    def collision_action(self):
        self.vy = ball.vy
        self.vx = ball.vx
        self.x += self.vx
        self.y += self.vy
        self.sprite.rect.topleft = [int(self.x), int(self.y)]

def gameQuit():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500), 0, 32)
ball = ball_class(screen)
wall = wall_class(screen)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    ball.move()
    ball.draw(screen)
    wall.draw(screen)
    is_a_collision = pygame.sprite.collide_mask(wall.sprite, ball.sprite)
    if is_a_collision:

        wall.collision_action()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            gameQuit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            ball.event(event)
    clock.tick(100)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: There are a lot of problems with your code.  I recommend you read up on general use of classes in Python, then read up on the sprite class in pygame, and then how masks work.  And really go deep with your reading.  There's too much to cover for this to be answered well on stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes, there probably are a lot of problems, but currently I am only trying to fix one. I'll work backwards from the solution to completely understanding everything.

Comment: I'm assuming that "ball.png" already has transparency?

Comment: There is something very messed up with your masks.  Try calling `wall.sprite.mask.outline()` and you will notice that it returns an empty list.  Same with the mask from `ball.sprite`.  You are doing some very strange things here (like extending `Sprite`, but then instead of filling the normal `Sprite` properties you create a `Sprite` property on the extended `Sprite` object, then add properties to that...).

Answer (score 0):

The bitmask collision *is* working in your code, but I think the code is making it more difficult because the sprite objects `ball_class` and `wall_class`, have separate sub-sprite objects defined inside them.

```
class ball_class(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, surface):
        self.surface = surface
        self.x = 250
        self.y = 250
        self.vy = 0
        self.vx = 0
        self.sprite = pygame.sprite.Sprite()    # <-- HERE
        ...
```

Generally when the code "subclasses" an existing class/object it *becomes* one of the same.  So it is not necessary to have a secondary sprite contained within the class.  This also makes the code and logic more involved, tricky and confusing.

Please consider this re-working of your `ball_class`:

```
class ball_class(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, surface):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)    # <-- HERE Must initialise sprites
        self.x     = 250
        self.y     = 250
        self.vy    = 0
        self.vx    = 0
        self.image = pygame.image.load("ball_64.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))
        self.mask  = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
```

Note the `image`, `rect` and `mask` member variables.  Previously the code was using these off the contained sprite.  But the PyGame library is written to expect these as members of the class, and it doesn't work properly if they're not defined.  Also your two sprite classes were not calling the base sprite initialiser function.

Here is a re-working of your code, which - when the ball hits the corner of the wall, collides properly (with bit-masks).

[image: ball_64.png] `ball_64.png`

[image: wall.png] `wall.png`

```
import pygame, sys, math
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

class ball_class(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, surface):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.surface = surface
        self.x = 250
        self.y = 250
        self.vy = 0
        self.vx = 0
        self.image = pygame.image.load("ball_64.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))
#        self.sprite.rect.topleft = [int(self.x), int(self.y)]
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)

    def event(self, event):
        if event.key == K_UP:
            self.vy = -1
            self.vx = 0
        elif event.key == K_DOWN:
            self.vy = 1
            self.vx = 0
        elif event.key == K_LEFT:
            self.vx = -1
            self.vy = 0
        elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
            self.vx = 1
            self.vy = 0

    def move(self):
        self.y += self.vy
        self.x += self.vx
        self.rect.topleft = [int(self.x), int(self.y)]
        #self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.sprite.image)

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def position(self):
        return self.rect()

class wall_class(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, surface):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.x = 250
        self.y = 100
        self.vy = 0
        self.image = pygame.image.load("wall.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))
#        self.sprite.rect.topleft = [int(self.x), int(self.y)]
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface( self.image )

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def collision_action(self, by_sprite_at ):
        print("wall_class.collision_action( by_sprite_at=%s )" % ( str( by_sprite_at ) ) )
#        self.vy = ball.vy
#        self.vx = ball.vx
#        self.x += self.vx
#        self.y += self.vy
#        self.sprite.rect.topleft = [int(self.x), int(self.y)]

def gameQuit():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500), 0, 32)
ball = ball_class(screen)
wall = wall_class(screen)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    screen.fill((128,128,128))
    ball.move()
    ball.draw(screen)
    wall.draw(screen)
    is_a_collision = pygame.sprite.collide_mask(wall, ball)
    if is_a_collision:
        wall.collision_action( ball.rect.center )

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            gameQuit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            ball.event(event)
    clock.tick(100)
    pygame.display.update()
```